# The position of a noun when there is two-verb "get over"

Tags: word-usage, verbs, phrasal-verbs

From [the Longman dictionary definition of get over](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/get-over), there are many uses of a two-verb "get over" but I picked up a few which would clarify what makes me confused.

> 1. get **something** over (also get something over with) : to do and finish something difficult that you have to do
>    *I’ll be in touch once I’ve got my exams over.*
> 2. get over **something** :  to begin to feel better after a very upsetting experience
>    *She never got over the death of her son.*

And from this, I assumed the meaning is changed depending on the position of noun.

Originally, I had thought that when I use two-verbs, I should place a noun between the components of two-verb if the noun is like "me, him, it, etc".

And it makes conflict If I want to use the noun "it" and the verb "get over" as the second meaning that I mentioned above because "get over it" is what I think grammatically wrong.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [phrasal verb](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/phrasal-verbs)s and phrasal verbs can be *separable* or *inseparable*.

For example "take back" (meaning return something to a shop) is separable.  You can say "I will take back the shirt", but you can also say "I will take the shirt back".  When you use a pronoun, you must separate:  "I will take it back"

On the other hand "look for" (meaning search) is inseparable.  You can say "I will look for the shirt", but it is ungrammatical to say "I will look the shirt back". Even with a pronoun, you must not separate:  "I will look for it".

What you have is an interesting example.  "Get over" is usually inseparable in the sense of "overcome":

> I got over my fear of flying.  I got over it.

But there is a sense in which it may be separable: If you mean "communicate successfully"

> To get your message over to a group of teenagers, you should not talk down to them.